# How to expose service layer with public and internal endpoints in Azure

Tags: wcf, azure, architecture, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I have a web app that talks to a service layer via WCF. These need to be internal endpoints and should be .net TCP bindings. However I also have some services in the service layer that don't need to be consumed internally but need to be exposed to the outside world i.e. http/https input endpoints. What is the best way in implementing this in Azure?

I was hoping someone could provide clarification / advice on the following points:

- If I use internal endpoints are these load balanced? There seems to be a lot of contradicting info around the web. I have read that you need to implement your own algorithm, but I have also read that this has now been implemented by Microsoft and it is automatic.
- Should the service layer be a web role or a worker role? It seems that there is a bit of a workaround to get internal TCP bindings working with a web role?
- Is there a specific set of guidelines as to which one to use? i.e. web role or worker role.
- I am assuming I am going to need two instances regardless of whether or not I use a web role or worker role? but wouldn't this depend on the first point? i.e. if there is no load balancer is there even any point in having 2 worker role instances?
- Would it be better to split my service layer into two layers? One to expose the internal endpoints and another to expose the public endpoints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

My previous answer got truncated. Take a look at Azure Service bus, you can create relays there to expose your internal WCF services

Comment: Consider editing your existing answer rather than making a new one.

Comment: Is this a place to help developers or to complain about the given help?

Comment: @Peter This place is for creating a large Q&A collection;  having random half-complete posts lying around isn't helping anybody.  Removing your first answer would've taken less time than replying in this way, and would prevent you from getting downvoted for no good reason since your advice here is fine, if a little terse (OP wants TCP bindings, not SB relays, though relays can be used to synchronize two instances).

Answer (score -2):

You can use a service relay for this, take a look @ Azure

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, but may help in solving it. It's best to post things like this as comments on the original question.